# Python - parsing and updating json

Tags: python, json

I'm able to load and parse a json file with Python by referring to list items by name. My users.json data file:

```
{
    "joe": {
        "secret": "abc123.321def"
    },
    "sarah": {
        "secret": "led789.321plo"
    },
    "dave": {
        "secret": "ghi532.765dlmn"
    }
}
```

My code - to output the 'secret' value associated with a specific user (e.g. Dave):

```
import json

with open('users_sample.json') as f:
  users = json.load(f)
  # f.close()

print(users['dave']['secret'])
```

This outputs Dave's secret:

```
ghi532.765dlmn
```

That's easy enough when I can predict or know the user names, but how do I iterate through each user in the users.json file and output each user's 'secret' value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `f.close()` is not needed, that's what the `with ...` is for.

Comment: Have you googled "iterate over dict" "update dict value" ?

Comment: Loading the JSON object gives you a Python dict, which you can use as usual.

Comment: do you want to output the secret value or simply update it; or I guess maybe output the *before/after* of the secret value, before writing it out to a file?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @azro I have not as I'm not that familiar with the json structure and object names. I'll do some googling, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: follow-up question, but do you already have a `dict` object with the replacements ideally planned for each user? for example, a new secret for joe, and one for dave, and so on down the road.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for your pointers, I didn't know that about with... I will remove that. I'll have to dig a bit on the options for the dict, perhaps once I understand the terminology around the json structure that will help.

Comment: Ignore the JSON part. Once you decoded it (`json.load(f)`) it has no relation to JSON any more.

Comment: @rv.kvetch those are helpful questions - I want to parse the value and update it by replacing the . with a + and then output to a file. I don't have a dict object but the new values will be based on the old values - for now simply replacing the . with a +

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt aha... I hear you - so I will spend a bit of time digging into the python equivalent types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the dictionary using a for loop

code that works:

```
import json

with open('users_sample.json') as f:
  users = json.load(f)

for user in users:
    print(f"user name: {user} secret: {users[user]['secret']}")
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer with easily readable code. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I would encapsulate the logic to print each user and their associated function into a helper function:

```
def print_users(users_dict: dict, header='Before'):
    print(f'-- {header}')
    for u in users_dict:
        print(f'  {u}: {users_dict[u].get("secret", "<empty>")}')
```

Then, upon loading the `users` object initially via `json.load`, you can then call the function like so:

```
print_users(users)
```

To replace the secret for each user, in this case to replace every occurrence of a dot `.` with a plus `+`, a simple approach could be to use a `for` loop to update the `users` object in place:

```
for name, user in users.items():
    if 'secret' in user:
        user['secret'] = user['secret'].replace('.', '+')
```

Then print the result after the replacements are carried out:

```
print_users(users, 'After')
```

Finally, we can write the result `users` object back out to a file:

```
with open('users_sample_UPDATED.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(users, out_file)
```

The output of the above code, in this case would be:

```
-- Before
  joe: abc123.321def
  sarah: led789.321plo
  dave: ghi532.765dlmn
-- After
  joe: abc123+321def
  sarah: led789+321plo
  dave: ghi532+765dlmn
```

---

The full code:

```
import json


def main():
    with open('users_sample.json') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    print_users(users)

    new_users = {name: {'secret': user['secret'].replace('.', '+')}
                 for name, user in users.items()}

    print_users(new_users, 'After')

    with open('users_sample_UPDATED.json', 'w') as out_file:
        json.dump(new_users, out_file)


def print_users(users_dict: dict, header='Before'):
    print(f'-- {header}')
    for u in users_dict:
        print(f'  {u}: {users_dict[u].get("secret", "<empty>")}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Some very helpful code in there @rv.kvetch, particularly the write to file piece, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested dictionary - i.e., each value associated with a top-level key is also a dictionary. You can iterate over those dictionaries with the built-in *values()* function. This leads to:

```
print(*[e.get('secret') for e in users.values()], sep='\n')
```